# Android fragment navigation inside a Tab Item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentmanager

I have a TabLayout application.
In the first tab, I would like to show a RecyclerView with Movies and by clicking them to show Movie Details.
I have already included a TabLayout + View Pager, and have extended FragmentPagerAdapter. At present, I can navigate between tabs (fragments with success).
The problem is that I cannot navigate from MoviesFragment to MovieDetailFragment (when the first tab is selected).
I have no idea what containerViewId should be declare, and how to pass data.

```
                Fragment fragment = new MovieDetailFragment();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.pager, fragment)
                    .commit();
```

The SecondFragment is instantiated but is not visible. 
R.id.pager: is the ViewPager component in my Main Activity.

Comment: why dont you show a dialog fragment for that

Comment: I dont think it is a good solution, regarding UX

Answer (score 0):

**Home Activity**

```
SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new 
SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener);
setupTabIcons(tabs);
```

**Adapter class**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return new HomeFragment();
            case 1: return Fragment2();
            case 2: return Fragment3();
            case 3: return Fragment4();
            default: return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: As i wrote, the tab bar is working. I have already included the above code in my App. The problem is that HomeFragment is a List of items (movies), if you click in an item then a detail page is shown. How to implement this, how can i navigate inside a tabitem